# EfCore Include Related object on Add

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to do this, but entry.Entity.User is NULL.

```
var entry = this.myContext.Verifications.Add(new DbVerification()
        {
            UserId = model.UserId,
            Created = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            Method = model.VerificationType
        });
entry.Entity.User.FirstName = "peanut";
```

I can explicitly load the user with

```
this.myContext.Users.First(x => x.Id == model.UserId)
```

but can i Include the entry.Entity.User object somehow without doing this ?

Just like I can do this

```
this.myContext.Verifications.Include(x => x.User).Where(doesntmatter);
```

to include the user object in the entity, is there anyway to include it in a similiar way using context.Verifications.Add as shown above.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, also `myContext` doesn't have an `Add` method, are you missing the DbSet name there?

Comment: yes i was missing a dbset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is use ***Explicit Loading***:

```
var entry = this.myContext.Verifications.Add(new DbVerification()
        {
            UserId = model.UserId,
            Created = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            Method = model.VerificationType
        });
context.Entry(entry.Entity).Reference(p => p.User).Load();// Add this line
entry.Entity.User.FirstName = "peanut";
```

But at the end if you don't have the user entity instance in memory you're going to need to do a round trip to fetch the user and make the change, so there is not much difference compared with this:

```
var entry = this.myContext.Verifications.Add(new DbVerification()
            {
                UserId = model.UserId,
                Created = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                Method = model.VerificationType
            });
var user=this.myContext.Users.First(x => x.Id == model.UserId);
user.FirstName = "peanut";
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: what do you mean by user entity instance in memory ? The first example worked for me

Comment: load the `user` in memory using,eg, `FirstOrDefault` or `Find` method

Comment: Both code examples will work, but the point is at the end you need to go to your db to load the user entity

Comment: Oh, yea i know performance wise it probably doesnt matter, but for code maintainability the first example was what I needed. Thanks

Comment: except it should be context.Entry(entry.entity).Reference... :)